# "Bumped to the homepage by Community"

Tags: discussion

I see that questions with no accepted answer or no answer are "bumped to the homepage by Community". I have a few questions about this,

1. Is this because there is no accepted answer or no answer?
2. Does it show up automatically?
3. Apart from an accepted answer, how can we managed it?
4. If OP has shown his/her satisfaction in the comments then what happens?

My efforts in this regards are, that I keep asking the questioner to accept an answer or clarify his/her question more. Am I doing the right thing?

If my question doesn't make any sense then let me know, I will delete it?

Comment: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

Comment: I have seen this as well for the first time and wondered what exactly are the circumstances that this happens. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I think it is when there are no positively voted answers, but I'm not sure.
2. Yes, it's automatically done by some batch process.
3. Write a new answer, improve an existing one, or vote to close the question if it is unanswerable.
4. Post an answer-in-comment as a formal answer.  Use *community wiki* if it is a verbatim cut and paste job.

> I keep asking the questioner to accept an answer or clarify his/her question more. Am I doing the right thing?

Mostly, but don't pester someone to Accept an answer; instead ask if there is something missing and be genuinely interested in helping if there is.  There is no obligation to Accept an answer even when it would seem the right thing to do.

Comment: Towards 1.: [Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/310499)